# Bootstrap remove button click effect

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to find the relevant css that I need to change in Bootstrap to prevent this effect on clicking a button (see attached image)

[image]

Any help would much most appreciated!

EDIT : Here is the relevant code :

```
    <div class="btn-group" dropdown container="body">
                        <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn dropdownToggle" style="background-color:#337ab7;color:white;">
                            Views <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
</div>
```

EDIT 2 : I managed to remove the border with this code :

```
.btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,
.btn:active.focus,
.btn.active.focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

However, there is still an effect when I click on the button (see image below) :

[image]

Is it possible to also remove this?

Comment: did you try `outline: 0` and/or `border: 0`?

Comment: Use F12 and search for the HTML. Does the HTML have JavaScript calls to a function? It could be run-time CSS in JavaScript or it will come up in the F12 when doing element selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the default outline, here's a generic dropdown example with bootstrap 3.3.7 without outline:

```css
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown 
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to set `.btn:focus {outline: 0;}`. If you need to remove focus globally just use this `:focus {outline: 0;}`

For the second question just use

```
.btn.active, 
.btn:active {
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can only accept one answer so I upvoted your post instead

Comment: This worked for me the other answers did not.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a line of css that over-rides the bootstrap, like:

```
button {
border:0!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to remove the shadowing:

```
.btn.active, .btn:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```